# Registering only employees in Laravel

Tags: php, validation, laravel

I am trying to register users in my Laravel app. I only want to register users who are already in the employees table. How do I do it?

```
protected function validator(array $data) {
    $names = \App\ Employee::all() - > lists('name') - > toArray();
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255|in_array:names',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to make a request to your Employee table, you can achieve this using the validation rule [exists](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-exists) :

**exists:table,column**

`The field under validation must exist on a given database table.`

**PHP**

```
protected function validator(array $data) {
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255|exists:employee,name',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);
}
```

Comment: This is fine. I think the `email` field should be the one you should check and not the `name`, since it is a unique identifier.

Comment: No, it's the name ;,) look OP question

Comment: Ok thanks, yes i saw it but i think he should do this check with emails and not names.